# Libgdx Screen NullPointerException when switching screens

Tags: java, android

I started trying to create a TestGame. Currently having an NPE and after spending hours on google and trying everything I could think of I can't seem to understand what I'm overlooking or forgetting. I had everything in one class and all worked perfectly. Though I wanted to create a GUI where I could switch between a MainMenu and PlayScreen. My MainMenu class works fine, though when I hit my neat little "play" button to enter the PlayScreen class I get these errors:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.me.game.PlayScreen.render(PlayScreen.java:90)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
at com.me.game.TestGame.render(TestGame.java:27)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:214)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
```

Playscreen error:

```
batch.draw(player.getCurrentFrame(), player.getPosition().x , player.getPosition().y);
```

Game error:

```
if (screen != null) screen.render(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
```

TestGame error:

```
super.render();
```

**TestMenu class** (Game class)

```
public class TestGame extends Game {

Game game;

@Override
public void create() {
    game = this;
    setScreen(new MainMenu(game));

public void render() {
    super.render();
}
```

**MainMenu** class

```
public class MainMenu implements Screen{

SpriteBatch batch;
Game game;
Stage stage;

public MainMenu(Game game){
    this.game = game;

public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.act();  

    batch.begin();
    stage.draw();
    batch.end();

}

 public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                     game.setScreen(new PlayScreen(game));
                     stage.clear();
                      return true;
```

**PlayScreen**

```
public class PlayScreen implements Screen {

SpriteBatch batch;
Player player;
Game game; 
Texture playerTexture;

       public PlayScreen(Game game){
        this.game = game;

    }

 public void render(float delta) {

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.begin();

        batch.draw(player.getCurrentFrame(), player.getPosition().x , player.getPosition().y);

        }

        player.update();

        batch.end();

 }

public void show() {                        
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
```

**Player class**

```
public class Player {
Texture playerTexture ;
Vector2 position;
String textureLoc;

 public Player(Vector2 position, String textureLoc){
            this.position = position;                
            movement = "";

            playerTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Character.png"));

public String getTextureLoc() {
        return textureLoc;
    }

    public void setTextureLoc(String textureLoc) {
        this.textureLoc = textureLoc;
    }
```

The most helpful was [Libgdx Screen NullPointerException when referencing another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23962321/libgdx-screen-nullpointerexception-when-referencing-another-class) where the problem also seems to be that I didn't initialize player in the PlayerScreen class at the show method. Though when I do fill player = new Player(position, textureLoc); in under the show method

```
public void show() {                        
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        player = new Player(position, textureLoc);
```

I get other errors

```
at com.me.game.Player.<init>(Player.java:50)
at com.me.game.PlayScreen.show(PlayScreen.java:90)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61)
at com.me.game.MainMenu$1.touchDown(MainMenu.java:90)
```

Which point to:

```
bounds = new Rectangle(position.x, position.y, currentFrame.getRegionWidth(), currentFrame.getRegionHeight());

player = new Player(position, textureLoc);

game.setScreen(new PlayScreen(game));
```

Though I assume it has something to do with the player not being initialized correctly? Anyhow for some reason I just can't seem to solve this. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is right here

```
player = new Player(position, textureLoc);
```

position and textureLoc are placeholders, these parameters you created are as follows

```
Vector2 position, String textureLoc
```

This means you need to create a new Vector2 and place it where position is and a String and place it where textureLoc is.

Try the following code instead, which will place your player approximately in the middle of the screen.

```
player = new Player(new Vector2(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2), "I am not sure why you put this parameter here");
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple, cant believe I didn't realise this. You're my hero of the day! Thanks for your clear and fast reply, if I had the required rep I would've voted up your answer! :). You have no idea how happy you just made me.